# How to pass the value to the End point

Tags: integration

> My old API Call was  https://api.fixer.io/latest. My Endpoint was updated to: https://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY.

Fixer Link:
https://github.com/fixerAPI/fixer#readme

> ***My Old code snippets:***

```
 public Static Decimal ExchangeRateGet(String Dates, String base, String Symbols){
  String body = '';
    Decimal exchangerates = null;
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('http://api.fixer.io/latest?base='+base+'&symbols='+symbols+'&date='+dates);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    HttpResponse  res = !Test.isRunningTest() ? new Http().send(req): null; 
    if(res != null)
     body = res.getbody();
     System.debug(body);
     fromJSON frmjsn;
     if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
        frmjsn = fromJSON.parse(body);
     }
     else{
         String bod='{"base":"GBP","date":"2015-03-27","rates":{"USD":1.4875}}';
          frmjsn = fromJSON.parse(bod);
     }
```

***It shows following message in debug:***
[image]

*How can I pass access key and other paremters like Dates,base and symbol to new endpoint.*

Useful Links:

https://fixer.io/documentation#latestrates

I need to pass following paremeters like dates.base,symbol.will it work in free edition.I can hit the url in free edition and but passing parameter is not working

Comment: Have you updated the Remote Site Setting with the new Endpoint URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the free edition and get the api key and append it to the **your_key**
Below is the example how to hit the api once you get the key.

```
https://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=13asdaslrkwelrkuou21o3.
```